# SQL Server - Database Design - Best Practices

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, database-normalization

We are developing an ASP.NET application and carrying out the database design too.

Kindly let me know if you know any best reference document for SQL Server database design - best practices.

Comment: Do you mean "data design" i.e. tables, indexes, normalization, etc., or the higher level "database design" where you might be considering fault tolerance, backup strategies, federated systems with replication, etc.?

Comment: Hi Trevor... I mean tables, indexes, normalization, etc.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Read up on SO for normalization.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization?sort=votes

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[database]%20design&tab=votes

Comment: SO is this site you are reading right now: "S"tack "O"verflow

Comment: If you've not looked already, see the resources on the SQL Server Central website too. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/